# My form submits data even if it is invalid. But my validation works fine

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

My code follows:.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Testing the textarea</title>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<span id="error_box" style="display:none;"></span>
<form name="storyTeller" method="get" action="#" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
<p class="title">
<label for="title">TITLE:</label>
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" required onBlur="validateTitle(title)"/>
</p>
<textarea name="entry" id="entry" rows="10" cols="45" onBlur="validateEntry(entry)">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Content of validation.js:

```
function validateTitle(title){/*validating the title*/
if (isNaN(document.getElementById('title').value)){
document.getElementById('title').style.background="#ccffcc";
document.getElementById('error_box').style.display="none";
return true;
}
else{
document.getElementById('error_box').innerHTML='Please enter a valid title';
document.getElementById('error_box').style.display="block";
document.getElementById('title').style.background="red";
return false;
}
}
function validateEntry(entry){/*validating the entry*/
var x=document.getElementById('entry').value;
x = x.trim();
if((x=="")||(x==null)){
document.getElementById('entry').style.background="red";
document.getElementById('error_box').innerHTML = 'Where is your story';
document.getElementById('error_box').style.display="block";
return false;
}
else{
document.getElementById('entry').style.background="#ccffcc";
document.getElementById('error_box').innerHTML='';
document.getELementById('error_box').style.display="none";
return true;
}
}
function validateForm(){/*validating the form*/
var error = 0;
if(!validateTitle('title')){
document.getElementById('error_box').style.display="block";
error++;
}
if(!validateEntry('entry')){
document.getElementById('error_box').style.display="block";
error++;
}
if(error > 0){
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction in "form submits invalid data, but validation works fine".

Comment: I mean if the form submits invalid data then it means validation is *not* working fine... but nevermind.

Comment: Would you mind to sort it out??

Comment: Placing the code from your external JS file into an html comment isn't very helpful. I've edited your question with my best guess at what you _really_ have. The result seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/qwnJC/ Why are you using `isNaN()` on a title?

Comment: Please describe the problem in terms of what happens, not with abstract (and self-contradictory) words. Specify how you filled out the form, how you tried to submit, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened. Also identify the browser(s) used.

Answer (score 0):

make the submit button as a normal button; and when it is clicked to call the final validation function, at the end of the function you must submit the form manually if everything is right

example :

```
<script>
function val(){
    if(document.getElementById('tb').value != "")
    document.getElementById('frm').submit();
    else alert('fill the text field');
}
</script>
<form id="frm" action="#">
    <input type="text" id="tb"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="submit" onclick="val()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What? Why not use the `onsubmit=` event on the form element as the OP had? It works: http://jsfiddle.net/qwnJC/

Comment: because onsubmit happens right when you submit and you want to validate your fields before you submit. then you can decide whether to submit or display warnings. you have the control. I hope it helped.

Comment: @Narwen you are using getELementById which is wrong in the entry validation, it is supposed to be getElementById no capital L. this might be one of the reasons

Comment: You can cancel the submit from within an `onsubmit` handler. There is no need to change to use a (non-submit) button instead. Obviously the OP has some other problem, but it's not related to use of `onsubmit`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I can't see another problem other than the misspelling in getELementById

Comment: Hi, onclick="val()" does not run, if I just press enter in title field. no validation hapens.

Comment: fix the ELement misspelling first and the enter thing is another issue

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your scrip in function validateEntry()

change line:

document.getELementById('error_box').style.display="none";

to line:

document.getElementById('error_box').style.display="none";

Comment: Thanks alot!! My bad really!!Just ashamed of myself.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code so now it works better for both submit and blur events.
In your HTML source change both `onblur` attributes to `onblur="validateEntry(this)"` and then you can use this javascript:

```js
function validateEntry(entry) { /*validating*/
    var error_box = document.getElementById('error_box');
    error_box.style.display = "none";
    if (entry.name == "title") { // INPUT type="text"
        if (!isNaN(entry.value)) {
            error_box.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid title';
            error_box.style.display = "block";
            entry.style.background = "#fee";
            return false;
        } else {
            entry.style.background = "#ccffcc";
            return true;
        }
    } else if (entry.name == "entry") { // TEXTAREA
        var x = entry.value.trim();
        if ((x == "") || (x == null)) {
            error_box.innerHTML = 'Where is your story?';
            error_box.style.display = "block";
            entry.style.background = "#fee";
            return false;
        } else {
            entry.style.background = "#ccffcc";
            return true;
        }
    }
}

function validateForm() { /*validating the form*/
    var form = document.forms['storyTeller'];
    var error_box = document.getElementById('error_box');
    var error = 0;
    var error_msg = '';
    if (!validateEntry(form['title'])) {
        error++;
        error_msg += error_box.innerHTML + '<br/>';
    }
    if (!validateEntry(form['entry'])) {
        error++;
        error_msg += error_box.innerHTML;
    }
    if (error > 0) {
        error_box.innerHTML = error_msg;
        error_box.style.display = "block";
        return false;
    } else {
        error_box.style.display = "none";
        return true;
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4TTv/)