# how to pass text value to another form which is assigned using php

Tags: php, javascript, html

i assign a text box value from a php variable and now i need to pass that value to another form, i'm able to receive other text box values in another page but couldn't get the value of the text box which i assigned using php variable...

```
<form name="form1" action="book.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name ="name" id="name" value="XXX">
<input type="text" name="da" id="da" value='<?php echo $output?>'>
<input type="submit" value="BOOK" name="book" onClick="return validate()">
</form>
```

in book.php

```
if(isset($_POST['book']))
{
$da = $_POST['da'];
$name= $_POST['name'];
echo "$name";
```

here i get the value for name but not for da...

Comment: Have you prevented the default submit event?

Comment: by using a normal button and submitting manually, I wrote that just now check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130827/my-form-submits-data-even-if-it-is-invalid-but-my-validation-works-fine/17130963#17130963

Comment: no, i didn't prevent it...

Comment: about the php value, try checking it on your browser's inspection and see the value in the html. what is it ?

Comment: if i print or echo the value on same page means its printed but i can't able to pass the assigned text value to another page, help me pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a semi-colon after the PHP `echo` command:

```
<input type="text" name="da" id="da" value='<?php echo $output; ?>'>
```

Comment: @Ganesh that's fine. Thanks for the 15 rep ;)

Comment: This is funny, because semicolon is absolutely optional in this case.

Comment: @dfsq maybe the command is running over to the tags without the semi colon? I thought semi colons were mandatory in PHP...

Comment: Just tested it with `<?php $a='a';echo $a?>` and [it works ok](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038745/do-i-need-a-trailing-semicolon-here) so unless Ganesh don't show the generated form, it's uncertain to determine the real problem. Apostrophes or quotes maybe?

Comment: "you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block". http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: @Stano maybe it's to do with the value of $output?

Comment: I dunno, it's a question for Ganesh. Maybe we are something missing and your advice is right.